# Drawings of rulers (centimeter & inches) mysteriously appear in headers and footers

Tags: koma-script, overleaf, scrlayer-scrpage, technical-environment

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\begin{document}
Hello world.
\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image: this just suddenly happened - also in the footer]

(plus something similar in the footer)

I'm using Overleaf. I assume there is something wrong with my environment. But what? I'm compiling with pdfLaTeX from their provided 2019 version of TeXLive. Although it's the same for 2017, and also switching to XeLaTeX in fact.

I've also tried clearing the temporary files, to no avail. I have of course contacted Overleaf support, but I figured maybe someone here gets a kick out of figuring this one out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Tom from Overleaf Support here.)

This is a side effect of the **Compile Mode → Fast [draft]** setting in your project. This setting can be found under the **Recompile** button, and changing back to **Normal** should help.

The reson why this happens is that the **Fast [draft]** mode passes the `draft` option to all classes and packages, and a side-effect of the `draft` mode for `scrlayer-scrpage` includes the rulers.

Comment: Thank you! That was fast. Curious that it does this.

Comment: @user207046 For some packages, the side-effect of `draft` is addition of some useful extra bits. E.g. the package `showlabels` (which displays labels when they're created and cited/refd) has `draft` by default, and setting `final` hides the labels.

Comment: @user207046 Use option `draft=false` for package `scrlayer-scrpage`: `\usepackage[draft=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}` to avoid the rulers if global option `draft` is set.